# NPM Install not working with artifactory behind proxy

Tags: node.js, npm, artifactory

I have configured artifactory and npm to work behind a proxy:

`npm config set registry http://myserver:8081/artifactory/api/npm/npmjs`

When I call `npm info bower` it works fine but the tarball URL already looks suspicous: `{ tarball: 'http://myserver:8081/artifactory/api/npm/npmjs/registry.npmjs.org/bower/-/bower-1.3.12.tgz', shasum: '37de0edb3904baf90aee13384a1a379a05ee214c' }`

`npm install bower` fails because of the wrong tarball URL. This is the relavant output of my npm-debug.log:

```
34 silly mapToRegistry registry http://myserver:8081/artifactory/api/npm/npmjs
35 silly mapToRegistry uri http://myserver:8081/artifactory/api/npm/npmjs/bower
36 verbose addRemoteTarball http://myserver:8081/artifactory/api/npm/npmjs/registry.npmjs.org/bower/-/bower-1.3.12.tgz not in flight; adding
37 verbose addRemoteTarball [ 'http://myserver:8081/artifactory/api/npm/npmjs/registry.npmjs.org/bower/-/bower-1.3.12.tgz',
37 verbose addRemoteTarball   '37de0edb3904baf90aee13384a1a379a05ee214c' ]
38 info retry fetch attempt 1 at 11:39:11
39 info attempt registry request try #1 at 11:39:11
40 http fetch GET http://myserver:8081/artifactory/api/npm/npmjs/registry.npmjs.org/bower/-/bower-1.3.12.tgz
41 http fetch 404 http://myserver:8081/artifactory/api/npm/npmjs/registry.npmjs.org/bower/-/bower-1.3.12.tgz
42 error fetch failed http://myserver:8081/artifactory/api/npm/npmjs/registry.npmjs.org/bower/-/bower-1.3.12.tgz
```

The part `registry.npmjs.org` in the URL is wrong and the correct tarball URL should be this one: `http://myserver:8081/artifactory/api/npm/npmjs/bower/-/bower-1.3.12.tgz`. From this URL I can downlaod the tarball manually using curl.

Any ideas if I have configured something wrong or if there is a bug somewhere?

Artifactory v3.4.2, npm v2.5.1

Comment: Does the NPM client has to pass via the proxy to reach Artifactory?

Comment: No, npm connects directly to Artifactory, the Proxy is behind Artifactory. We got an Artifactory update to 3.4.2., before we had 3.2.0 and everything was fine.

Comment: This can happen when the repository URL does not match the base tarball returned by the registry. Which URL are you using for the Artifactory remote repository? Can you run the same npm info command directly (bypassing Artifactory) and check the tarball URL?

Answer (score 1):

It can happen when the remote repository that should proxy the npmjs registry is pointing on the wrong URL (e.g. http://registry.npmjs.**com** instead of .org).

Answer (score 0):

Your Artifactory front end displays the correct string for the npm config

Does this match what your running ?

Mine looks like this

```
#Add this registry URL to your ~/.npmrc or use:
npm config set registry http://serverName:8081/artifactory/api/npm/npmjs
```

I'm just wondering if the config of the remote repo is correct in Artifactory

Another option is to try zapping the cache on the npm remote repo

Is there any info in the Artifactory system logs showing what its trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue when the package has a package-lock file with reference to npmjs.org. For example a file like this: https://github.com/mckn/gulp-nuget/blob/master/npm-shrinkwrap.json

I guess the only solution is using relative URLs in resolved field of the package-lock file.